# Why do I need to read from a tape 3 times to read 2 archives?

Tags: tar, io, storage, archive, tape

After writing two tar archives to a tape:

```
$ mt -f /dev/st0 rewind
$ tar cvf /dev/nst0 first
$ tar cvf /dev/nst0 second
```

Why do I need to read from the tape **three** times to read the **two** archives?

```
$ mt -f /dev/st0 rewind

$ mt -f /dev/nst0 status
SCSI 2 tape drive:
File number=0, block number=0, partition=0.
Tape block size 0 bytes. Density code 0x44 (LTO-3).
Soft error count since last status=0
General status bits on (41010000):
 BOT ONLINE IM_REP_EN

$ tar tvf /dev/nst0
drwxrwxr-x oskar/oskar       0 2017-03-23 11:35 first/

$ mt -f /dev/nst0 status
SCSI 2 tape drive:
File number=0, block number=10, partition=0.
Tape block size 0 bytes. Density code 0x44 (LTO-3).
Soft error count since last status=0
General status bits on (1010000):
 ONLINE IM_REP_EN

$ tar tvf /dev/nst0
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

$ mt -f /dev/nst0 status
SCSI 2 tape drive:
File number=1, block number=0, partition=0.
Tape block size 0 bytes. Density code 0x44 (LTO-3).
Soft error count since last status=0
General status bits on (81010000):
 EOF ONLINE IM_REP_EN

$ tar tvf /dev/nst0
drwxrwxr-x oskar/oskar       0 2017-03-23 11:37 second/

$ mt -f /dev/nst0 status
SCSI 2 tape drive:
File number=1, block number=3, partition=0.
Tape block size 0 bytes. Density code 0x44 (LTO-3).
Soft error count since last status=0
General status bits on (1010000):
 ONLINE IM_REP_EN
```

Comment: I only have a work-around not a solution: After first read then manually skip to next 'file' `mt -f /dev/nst0 fsf 1`

Comment: At the 2nd `mt -f /dev/nst0 status` it is still at the end of the first file.

Comment: @MikeD I don't have a tape drive right here and can not test it. But as I remember I have done exactly as Oskar did: just wrte several times to a drive and the read several times without the use `mt fsf 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the first `tar tvf`, the tape is left on the last block of the first file. The second `tar tvf` reads that again, and complains, but doing that leaves the tape on the first block of the second file so the third `tar tvf` works.

When working with multiple files on tape you should really use `mt` to move between the files before running `tar`:

```
mt -f /dev/st0 rewind
tar tvf /dev/nst0
mt -f /dev/nst0 fsf 1
tar tvf /dev/nst0
```